# How to exclude separate files with nonFilteredFileExtension

Tags: maven

I have this bundle.

```
admin.common.upper_case=Uma ou mais letras maiúsculas
```

During building project this bundle becomes corrupted.

```
admin.common.upper_case=Uma ou mais letras maiï¿½sculas
```

In order to fix issue we use this configuration for **maven-resources-plugin** 
Namely we added **nonFilteredFileExtension** tag for **properties** extension.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
        <nonFilteredFileExtensions>
            <nonFilteredFileExtension>properties</nonFilteredFileExtension>
        </nonFilteredFileExtensions>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This configuration caused issue with another property file like **build.properties** :

```
build.version=${project.version}
static.url.version=${project.build.timestamp}
```

We tried to use this configuration(namely added filter tag in order to filter build.properties file):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
        <filters>
            <filter>properties/build.properties</filter>
        </filters>
        <nonFilteredFileExtensions>
            <nonFilteredFileExtension>properties</nonFilteredFileExtension>
        </nonFilteredFileExtensions>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Also we tried with this configuration in order to avoid filtering for current bundles:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <configuration>
        <webResources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <!-- enable filtering -->
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>${basedir}/src/main/resources/one.properties</exclude>
                    <exclude>${basedir}/src/main/resources/two.properties</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </webResources>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The question is how to allow filtering only for this property file **build.properties**

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you should try to fix the root of your problem by [Specifying a character encoding scheme](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/encoding.html):

```
<project ...>
 ...
 <properties>
   <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
   ...
 </properties>
 ..
</project>
```

One way to do what you want is to specify files to include and files to excludes. From the [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html):

```
<project>
  ...
  <name>My Resources Plugin Practice Project</name>
  ...
  <build>
    ...
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/my-resources</directory>
        <includes>
          <include>**/*.txt</include>
        </includes>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*test*.*</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
      ...
    </resources>
    ...
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

The elements `include` and `exclude` should also works with specific files such as `path/to/abc.properties`.